# Flask Template - For Loop Iteration key:value

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I've got an HTML template with a Flask Jinja for loop in it which generates a table and looks like:

```
<tbody>
  {% for segment in segment_details %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{segment}}</td>
      <td>{{segment_details['{{segment}}']}}</td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

I'm trying to iterate through a document of varying length/keys and present each row in the table as the key and value.  In my Python code I've got this which has the desired response in the shell:

```
        for item in segment_details:
            print(item, segment_details[item])
```

But in Flask I get the item correctly listing all the rows but the

`{{segment_details['{{segment}}']}}`

Isn't producing any values, I've tried with and without the single quotes.  Is this possible?

Comment: Did you try removing the `{{ }}` around `segment`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is where your error is:

```
<td>{{segment_details['{{segment}}']}}</td>
```

There is no need for the `{{ }}` inside.
It should be just:

```
<td>{{segment_details[segment]}}</td>
```

For more see the documentation for [Jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/).
When you are writing a statement(`if`, `for`) in `Jinja2` you use `{% statement %}` but when you are accessing a variable then just use `{{ variable }}`.

Comment: Thanks Kemis - appreciate the quick response and your advice worked perfectly!

Comment: I was just reading because I was bored. I just learned something just now, thanks! Earned an upvote!

Answer (score 16):

it is a solution

```
<tbody>
  {% for key, segment in segment_details.items() %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ key }}</td>
      <td>{{ segment }}</td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```